# How can we treat dV like this?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, calculus

[image]

Now, to calculate the gravitational potential due to a ring(or any object for that matter) at a distance $r$ we consider a tiny mass $dm$ on the ring, and calculate the potential $dV$ due to this element giving $dV = Gdm/y$ and then "sum up the $dV$'s" (integrate) $=> V(y) = GM/y$. But really, $dV$ is the infinitesimal change in potential for an infinitesimal change in $y$, and $dV = V(y+dy)-V(y)$ doesn't seem to have any physical significance and doesn't seem to mean the potential due to $dm$. Then, how did we simply treat $dV$ as the potential due the element $dm$ and "sum these up" using integration?

I've always thought of integration as simply a way of solving a differential equation: for an infinitesimal change in the function $df(x)$ in the interval $dx$, $df(x) = f(x+dx)-f(x)$ to which we are supposed to assign a physical meaning and then write the differential equation & solve it. Why can we treat integration as summation of tiny $dF$'s or $dx's$

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/314449/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the case that $dV = V(y+dy) - V(y)$.

The problem with your reasoning is that $dV(y)$ isn't the change in potential due to small element of $y$, but rather $dV(y)$ is a small element of potential resulting from the small element of mass $dm$ located at position $y$.

Therefore by summing the $dV$ up, you are adding together the small bit of potential produced by each bit of mass $dm$ that makes up the ring.

Comment: @Pulzz that's incorrect, by definition dV = Gdm/y.  In this context dV is not V(y+dy) - V(y).  There is no "dy" in this case at all as y is constant.

Comment: I've always thought of integration as simply a way of solving a differential equation: for an infinitesimal change in the function $df(x)$ in the interval $dx$, $df(x) = f(x+dx)-f(x)$ to which we are supposed to assign a physical meaning and then write the differential equation & solve it. Why can we treat integration as the summation of tiny $df$'s or $dm's$ or $dV's$

Comment: @xasthor simply the way you've thought of integration isn't complete.  Integration is defined as summing up small elements.  In this case it is small elements of potential dV (due to the small elements of mass).  When you are doing area under a curve, you are summing small rectangles of width dx and height f(x), so you are summing small areas of area f(x)dx.  Integration is defined as summing many small entitites.

Comment: what kind of a graph would $dV = Gdm/y$ correspond to, and why would the area under that curve give me the total potential due to the ring?

Comment: @xasthor I wouldn't recommend thinking about this situation as a graph.  The graph comment was just another example of how integration works as a sum of small elements (rectangles).

Comment: I was asking for that because although intuitively it makes sense that integration is "summing up all the dV's" I want to know, rigorously, why we can write $dV$ for a tiny element $dm$ and then sum up these dV's using integration

Comment: @xasthor if this was a graph the x-axis would be mass ranging from 0 to M (the total mass of the ring) and the y-axis would be potential per unit of mass (potential density if you will) given by G/y.  This is constant (since each point on the ring has the same potential) and thus the graph would simply be a horizontal line.  The integral would then be the area under the curve which is the integral of G/y with respect to m, written as integral of Gdm/y

Answer (score 0):

You have written $ dV = \frac{Gdm}{y}$. So this tells you what *dV* actually is - It is potential due to small element of mass *dm*. We write it *dV* just because, its is not due to whole mass of ring but due to small part of it. We need to integrate this over whole mass to get *V*. In this case *dV* is not $$ V(y+dy) - V(y) $$ because y is not the variable with which we are dealing. In fact you must assume y to be constant while doing integration.